# Evaluating Internal`$VideoEncodings gives a strange message

Tags: undocumented, video

When calling `` Internal`$VideoEncodings `` to check available video codecs on my pc, Mathematica_11.3 gives a message:

> `` ImportExport`RegisterFormat::noexe: Could not install QuickTime.exe. ``

and the output is not a list but:

> `` System`ConvertersDump`out$26172 ``

I have installed QuickTime 7.7.9 from Apple, but it does not solve the problem.

I am using Windows 10 and Mathematica 11.3.

Is there anyone having the same problem?

#### Edit

I checked the same code with Mathematica 10.4.1 and it worked well!

Then I checked the installation directories of these two versions of Mathematica and searched for the file "QuickTime.exe". It turns out that this file exists in 10.4.1 but not in 11.3.0. I think this may causing this problem.

12/31/2018

Comment: This was posted here and to the community site.  Have you tried contacting wolfram customer support?  They may be best equipped to answer this.

Comment: @JasonB. Yes, i have reported this to the wolfram customer support, and just half a hour before I got a reply on the community site. It is a bug and will be fixed in 12.0.